# Blastn locally nt database search length < 16

Tags: blastn, makeblastdb

when I run a short search in blastn locally with less than 16 nucleotides with nt.00 database I don't get any found match, but if I increase the searched string 2 nucleotides it finds matches, so the 14 string was in the BD. Also, when I run the same 14  nucleotides search in a BD created with homo-sapiens Y chromosome it finds matches. This BD was created with the command:

```
makeblastdb -in homoy.fasta -out homoydb -dbtype 'nucl' -parse_seqids -hash_index
```

As you see it includes `-parse_seqids` `-hash_index` parameters.
The command for search is (replacing homoydb with nt.00 in the first case):

```
blastn -task blastn-short -query myqueryin.fa -db homoydb -out myout.txt
```

So why blast nt preformatted databases don't find sequences shorter than 16 if they are in the BD and with my own DB find them OK?